# MySQL/PHP output is not as expected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two tables in my database by name `language` and `language_variables`.

In `language` table, I have stored languages and in `language_variables` have value of specific word in all languages.

DB Structure & data of `language`

```
id, title, short_code, type enum('ltr', 'rtl'), default enum('yes', 'no'), status   enum('on', 'off')
1, English, en, ltr, yes, on
2, Urdu, ur, rtl, no, on
```

DB Structure & data of `language_variables`

```
id, language_id, keyword, value
1, 1, str_word, this is simple string
2, 2, str_word, اس سادہ سلک ہے
3, 1, str_word2, this is 2nd string
```

**Output I want**

I want to show keyword `str_word` for once and show drop down list of languages list for same keyword.

**Issue in my output**

[image: PlayHD.pk]

My SQL query is

```
SELECT
lv.id, lv.language_id, lv.keyword, lv.`value`, l.title
FROM language_variable AS lv
    INNER JOIN `language` AS l ON l.id = lv.language_id

GROUP BY lv.keyword
ORDER BY lv.id DESC
```

My view

```
<?php
foreach($records as $record)
{
?>
<div class="banner-row1">
    <div class="banner-row-text">
        <h2><?=$record->keyword?></h2>
        <p class="text-muted">
            <small>
            Value: <?=$record->value?><br />
            Languages: 
            <select id="language_id" required>
                <option></option>
                <?php
                foreach($languages as $language)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$record->id.'">'.$language->title.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            </small>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: please complete with the html output you want and the html output you get (and the php code containing how you generate $language and $records). And btw I see something wrong in your language loop, you display language title with record id as value (instead of language id).

Comment: @Asenar actually I want to display only language in dropdown list which is available and linked with `language_id` is DB.

Comment: There is still a "logic" problem in your code. `record->id` should not be in value if the label is `language->title`.

Comment: @Asenar you are right. Your point is correct I have changed the variable. As this will not solve the real issue.

Comment: do you want to display only the language name (`English`) or the actual value matching that language (`this is simple string `, or `English: this is simple string`)? (Btw you didn't changed your var in the view)

Comment: @Asenar I want to display language title in dropdown like English, Arabic, Urdu

Comment: So there is no relation between the languages in the select box and the "heading_2" / "value: Heading 2" thing ? Or maybe you just want, for each row in "language_variable" display the language name ? if yes, I don't see the reason why you need to even put a `<select>`. (And by the way there is still a logical problem in the select box, you show the id of the RECORD instead of the matching language )

Answer (score 1):

You should join with `language_id`, not with  `id` in `language_variables` table.

```
INNER JOIN `language` AS l ON lv.id = l.id
```

Use this

```
INNER JOIN `language` AS l ON l.id = lv.language_id
                                        ^         ^
```

Comment: Sorry there was typo in my question. I have updated my question again

Comment: I want to display only language in dropdown list which is linked with `language_id` is DB.

Comment: Spouse I have 500 records and `language_variables` and 6 languages in `language` table. So this method will run `3000` sub queries. I'm I right

Comment: check this once, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929102/retrieving-data-from-two-tables-in-codeigniter/33930486#33930486

Answer (score 1):

You need to do at least 2 queries (or change your whole code).

1) get all the "str_word" : query1 = `select distinct keyword from language_variable`

2) get all the values : query2 = `select * from language_variable`

3) do a foreach loop with query1, and inside it, display all the corresponding values  str_word.

That solution requires to have the query2 as an associative array indexed on str_word.

The alternative, easier to code but requiring more resources is to do the query1 then, in the loop, do the corresponding query `select * from language_variable where str_word=:that_keyword` (that means as many sql query as there is keywords)